# show form fields data based on radio button selection

Tags: javascript, jquery

A post can have many administrators, normally 4 or 5 administrators. I have a form to edit the administrators of a post.

This form has some radio buttons. Each radio button corresponds to a administrator of a a post.

For example if the post with id "1" has 4 administrators then it should appear on this edit administrators page form 4 radio buttons. Each radio button has a name of the administrators of the post. This is part is working with the "@foreach($administrators as $admin)...endforeach":

```
@foreach($administrators $admin)
      <div class="form-check">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="radiobutton" id="{{$admin->id}}" value="">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="">
          {{$admin->name}}
        </label>
      </div>
  @endforeach
```

Then, below the radio buttons, the form has some fields and I want to show in theses fields the information of each selected administrator (radio button).

I want that when each radio button (administrator) is selected show in the form fields (name, email etc) the information of each selected administrator so that the administrator details can be changed and then updated with "Update admin" button. This part Im not having success doing it. Do you know how to do this part properly?

I have this js below but its incomplete i dont know how to do the part to show in the form fields the information of each selected administrator, maybe its possible to do with the append method but how to do that properly? Because the form fields have the class .form-row others dont have so Im with doubts in this part.

**JS**

```
var admins = {!! $administrators !!} // $administrators is an array created from server

var id = $(".radio:checked").attr('id');

for ( var i = 0; i < admins.length; i++ ) {

    if(id==admins[i].id){
    }
}
```

In the source admins variable has this format:

```
var admins = [{"id":3,"name":"John","email":"emailtest1@test.email"},{"id":5,"nome":"Kate","email":"emailtest2@test.email","..."}]
```

**Full Form:**

```
<form method="post" class="clearfix">
      <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="administrator">Administrators</label>

          @foreach($administrators as $admin)
          <div class="form-check">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="radiobutton" id="{{$admin->id}}" value="">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="">
              {{$admin->name}}
            </label>
          </div>
          @endforeach

      </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" required class="form-control" value="{{ $admin->name}}" name="name" id="name">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <input type="number" min="1"
               required class="form-control" value="{{ $admin->email }}"
             name="email" id="email">
      </div>

      <div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="username">Username</label>
                <input type="text" 
                       required class="form-control" value="{{ $admin->username}}"
                       name="username" id="username">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="img">Image</label>
                <input type="file"
                       required class="form-control"
                       name="img" id="img">
            </div>
        </div>
      <!-- more fields -->
      </div>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Update admin"/>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `find` to find the id from the array.

```js
$(function() {
  var admins = [{"id":3,"name":"John","email":"emailtest1@test.email"},{"id":5,"name":"Kate","email":"emailtest2@test.email"}];

  $("input[name='radiobutton']").click(function() {
    let id = $(this).attr("id");

    //Find the id from the array, if not found, use a default value
    let data = admins.find(e => e.id == id) || {name: "", email: ""};

    //Update the textboxes
    $("input[name='name']").val(data.name);
    $("input[name='email']").val(data.email);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-check">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="radiobutton" id="3" value="">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="">
        John
  </label>
</div>
<div class="form-check">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="radiobutton" id="5" value="">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="">
        Kate
  </label>
</div>

<input type="text" required class="form-control" value="" name="name" id="name">
<input type="text" min="1" required class="form-control" value="" name="email" id="email">
```

Comment: Thanks! In my example its not working when I click in the radio button the form fields are not updated with that administration info. In the editor appears an error "Comparison administrator.find(....) may cause unepected type coercion. Also it appears let definitions are not supported by current js version. Maybe dont work because of those errors right? The error of the js version can be fixed using "var id" instead of "let id" but the other expression error do you know how to fix?

Comment: What browser are you using? `let` is new but supported by modern browsers

Comment: Im testing on chrome, the error appears in the text editor!

Comment: Ohh. What text editor? Maybe your text editor is not updated.

Comment: Thanks it is working!! It was not working because other error!

Comment: Happy to help :)